# How to make file comparison with other files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, comparison

I am new to python :( I want to make:

Main file (tokens):
beautiful 2
amazing 5
speechless 2

Folder with 73 files:

How can I write the script in python to check the source frequency for example:
The main folder the words to calculate in which sources appear:
**The results for example The word beautiful appears in 55 sources
The word amazing appears in 30 sources
The word speechless appears in 73 sources**

```
from os import listdir

with open("C:/Users/ell/Desktop/Archivess/test/rez.txt", "w") as f:
    for filename in listdir("C:/Users/ell/Desktop/Archivess/test/sources/books/"):
       with open('C:/Users/ell/Desktop/Archivess/test/freqs/books/' + filename) as currentFile:
            text = currentFile.read()

            if ('amazing' in text):
                f.write('The word excist in the file ' + filename[:-4] + '\n')
            else:
                f.write('The word do not excist in the file' + filename[:-4] + '\n')
```

I have written the code but only shows me the word that I write in for loop. How can I do this code for files? I appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the purpose of number in tokens file? Are you able to extract the tokens you want to look for?

Comment: I already have the tokens but now I want to compare to see from the main file where these tokens appear in other files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way.
After creating token list, go through each file and increment the count of token if it exists in the file.

```
import os

token_file = "token.txt"
main_dir = "PATH/TO/DIR"
with open(token_file, "r") as f:
    # Creates a dict with "token" as keys and 0 as values.
    # rstrip removes \n from token
    tokens = {token.rstrip(): 0 for token in f.readlines()}

for filename in os.listdir(main_dir): 
    path = os.path.join(main_dir, filename) # path to source file
    with open(path, "r") as fp:
        text = fp.read()
        for token in tokens.keys(): # check every token
            if token in text:       # if token found in text
                tokens[token] += 1  # increment token count
print(tokens)
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed; thank you so much I appreciate :)

Answer (score 0):

Before doing a loop on every file, you should firstly read the file containing your tokens to parse and store them into a list (or a dict, or anything you want), then checking if any element of this list is present in the file.

Dicts are convenient cause you can store the frequency of each word as values. For instance, you can do `{"beautiful": 0, "amazing": 0}`, then incrementing each value when its key appear in a file.

If your token file looks something like this...

```
amazing
beautiful
speechless
```

You can do something like that.

```py
with open("token_file.txt", "r") as f:
    # Creates a dict with "token" as keys and 0 as values.
    tokens = {token: 0 for token in f.readlines()}
# tokens = {"beautiful": 0, "amazing": 0, etc...}
```